# PendingIntent get lost after ~20minutes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am trying to do widget, which will update itself on click.
Co, I created following code, which works like a charm - but only for about 20minutes then it stopped working (it does not update on click anymore, but classic widget self-update after specified period in XML works)
It starts working again if I add another instance of widget, then all intents are registered again.

Have anyone else faced the problem? Can you see something wrong with my code?

In my widget Provider:

```
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                int[] appWidgetIds) {
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
            Log.d(tag, "onUpdate");

            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_exchange_rate_small);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExchangeRateWidgetService.class);
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                // Register onClick action for pendingIntent
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wdExchangeRate, pendingIntent);

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


                try {
                    // Perform first update
                    pendingIntent.send();
                } catch (CanceledException e) {
                    Log.e(tag, "First update has been canceled, this should not normally happend!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

How my service is declared:

```
 public class ExchangeRateWidgetService extends IntentService {

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    // Doing something ...

    }
    }
```

Comment: What for do you use the pendingIntent.send() call?

Comment: Well, it perform update itself, call the service which will retrieve data and update widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it, the problem was in `IntentService`, service updated widget via remote view, but does not registered `setOnClickPendingIntent`.